# ImageCapture -> takePhoto() method fails in windows 10

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am trying to capture an image via the camera using "video" tag. Found an example at 
https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/image-capture/grab-frame-take-photo.html
and developed my web application using the example. It works fine in Mac (mac os x el capitan) and chrome latest (62)
But fails on Windows X (Tested on a Surface pro) and chrome latest (62). Failure happens at **ImageCapture -> takePhoto()** method.
Finally found that above example also fails on Surface.
Please help me to get this sorted.

Comment: What error do you get in the browser console?

Comment: Can you try on an earlier (v61) Chrome? Chrome 62, at least on windows, is a buggy release in so many ways so far!!

Comment: I superseed @NewToJS request for a console error (replace `ChomeSamples` with `console` in all the `catch` blocks). Chrome did some security update regarding how they treat MediaStreams and cross-origin checks in the latests versions. I wouldn't be surprised it did mess something in this new API they didn't found out yet. Just to be sure, does [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jusLmf84/) works on your surface? Anyway, you might want to open an issue on their [bug-tracker](https://chromiumbugs.appspot.com), after you tested on the latest Chrome available (64 canary as of today).

Comment: yes it works fine but if you attempt to access a clients camera/mic over HTTP with chrome it will not work. You must use HTTPS as the report in the browser console states. I had this exact same issue with a webcam stream I had in place for one of my websites. **Example** [**HTTP demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jusLmf84/) **-**  [**HTTPS demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jusLmf84/)

Comment: @NewToJS then the error would raise in `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`, not in `imageCapture.takePhoto`.
And it would fail on osX too. Also, [provided link](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/image-capture/grab-frame-take-photo.html) uses `https:`  protocol. And the fiddle I did provide in my earlier comment was to test OP's device ability to do the exact same thing without using the ImageCapture API, in order to target this API as the really buggy part. Sorry I now understand you thought my comment was intended to you, while I was just referring to your own request for more info.